# Super Slow Manipulate with Heat Equation - - Assumption, and Interpolate

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate, interpolation, heat-equation

**Aim:** solve coupled heat equation with cubic source, use DensityPlot and observe how system will react to changes in parameter(like `k`and `kc` (0 for now)) values.

```
Clear[func, y]
kc = 0; 
func[k_] :=
 NDSolve[{
   D[y[t, x], t] == D[D[y[t, x], x], x] + y[t, x]^3 - z[t, x],
   D[z[t, x], t] == D[D[z[t, x], x], x] + y[t, x] - k*z[t, x] + kc,
   y[0, x] == 0.3, z[0, x] == 0,
   y[t, -2] == 0, z[t, -2] == 0,
   y[t, 2] == 1, z[t, 2] == 0
   },
  {y, z}, {t, 0, 5}, {x, -2, 2}]
Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[
  ({y[tt, xx] /. func[l]}),
  {tt, 0, 5}, {xx, -2, 2}
  ],
 {l, 0, 3, 1}
 ]
```

Manipulate is not functioning well. I think manipulate computes func[k] each step and its super slow due to double derivative terms. Therefore I thought about the following "solutions":

**Solution1**
Assume k is a real parameter, and solve equation system once for k. So, for each manipulation step plot for a new k value.

```
Clear[func, y]
kc = 0; 
(*func[k_]:=
NDSolve[{
D[ y[t,x],t]\[Equal]D[D[ y[t,x],x],x]+y[t,x]^3-z[t,x],
D[ z[t,x],t]\[Equal]D[D[ z[t,x],x],x]+y[t,x]-k*z[t,x]+kc,
y[0,x]\[Equal]0.3,z[0,x]\[Equal]0,
y[t,-2]\[Equal]0,z[t,-2]\[Equal]0,
y[t,2]\[Equal]1,z[t,2]\[Equal]0
},
{y,z},{t,0,5},{x,-2,2}]*)
solfunc[k] := Assuming[k ∈ Reals,
   NDSolve[{
    D[ y[t, x], t] == z[t, x],
    D[ z[t, x], t] == 
     D[D[ z[t, x], x], x] + y[t, x] - k*z[t, x] + kc,
    y[0, x] == 0.3, z[0, x] == 0,
    y[t, -2] == 0, z[t, -2] == 0,
    y[t, 2] == 1, z[t, 2] == 0
    },
   {y, z}, {t, 0, 5}, {x, -2, 2}]]
plotme[k_] := y[tt, xx] /. solfunc[k]
Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[
  ({plotme[k]}),
  {tt, 0, 5}, {xx, -2, 2}
  ],
 {k, 0, 3, 1}
 ]
```

Not worked.

**Question1**
Does anyone have any thoughts on how to do this?

**Solution2**

Use Table the solutions of NDSolve. But table-ing a continuous solution in a discrete way should lose of information.

**Question2**
(I would appreciate if anyone can give a hint.)

**Additional Question**

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to use interpolate in this set up?
(Later it turned out that `PlotPoints -> 100` worked fine instead interpolate)

Comment: The issue is not `Manipulate`, but `DensityPlot`: If you wrap the first argument in `Evaluate`, the performance will be a lot better: `DensityPlot[Evaluate[{plotme[k]}],...]` - if you don't do this, `plotme[k]` is indeed reevaluated for every point of the plot

Comment: Your initial and boundary condition contradict each other. E.g. y[0, x] == 0.3 and y[t, -2] == 0,  and  y[t, 2] == 1

Comment: @DanielHuber yes you are right.

Answer (score 5):

With your revised initial and boundary conditions

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

kc = 0;

eqns = {
    D[y[t, x], t] == D[D[y[t, x], x], x] + y[t, x]^3 - z[t, x],
    D[z[t, x], t] == D[D[z[t, x], x], x] + y[t, x] - k*z[t, x] + kc,
    y[0, x] == 0.3, z[0, x] == 0.1, y[t, -2] == 0.3, z[t, -2] == 0.1,
    y[t, 2] == 0.3, z[t, 2] == 0.1} // Rationalize;
```

Use [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, {y, z}, {t, 0, 5}, {x, -2, 2}, {k}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 yl = y[l] /. sol;
 DensityPlot[yl[t, x] /. sol, {t, 0, 5}, {x, -2, 2},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {t, x}),
  PlotLegends ->
   BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "y(t,\[ThinSpace]x)"]],
 {{l, 1}, 0, 3, 1, ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is the well-functioning code due to changes made according to commentators. thank you for your time.

````
Clear["Global`*"]

kc = 0; 
func[k_] :=
 NDSolve[{
   D[ y[t, x], t] == D[D[ y[t, x], x], x] + y[t, x]^3 - z[t, x],
   D[ z[t, x], t] == D[D[ z[t, x], x], x] + y[t, x] - k*z[t, x] + kc,
   y[0, x] == 0.3, z[0, x] == 0.1,
   y[t, -2] == 0.3, z[t, -2] == 0.1,
   y[t, 2] == 0.3, z[t, 2] == 0.1
   },
  {y, z}, {t, 0, 5}, {x, -2, 2}]
plotme[k_] := y[tt, xx] /. func[k]
Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[Evaluate[plotme[k]],
  {tt, 0, 5}, {xx, -2, 2}],
 {k, 0, 3, 1}]```
````